# Comparing Column Values With NA

Tags: r, dataframe

The input table below has data points which are `NA`. I understand in `R` when a value is compared with `NA` it leads to output being `NA`.

Is there still a way around so that I can still compare using `ifelse()` and make sure if one of the values being compared is `NA` then it will still provide output as if `NA` was a character/string being compared?

**Input Raw Data**

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "A B
                    NA  TEST
                   TEST TEST
                   Abaxasdas Test")
```

**Input Data Table**

```
 A       B
<NA>   TEST
TEST   TEST
Abaxasdas Test
```

**Code**

```
data$Output <- ifelse(as.character(data$A) == as.character(data$B), "YES", "NO")
```

**Output**

```
 A    B   Output
<NA> TEST  <NA>
TEST TEST  YES
Abaxasdas Test NO
```

**Expected Output**

```
 A    B   Output
<NA> TEST  NO
TEST TEST  YES
Abaxasdas Test NO
```

Comment: What is the desired output when both A and B are `NA`?

Comment: @JamesMartherus - `True`.  Not sure if I am being short sighted there, but for the data I am using both column value being `NA` means both are blank and that's `TRUE` for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To simplify things, let's first redefine the data frame with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`:

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "A B
                     NA  TEST
                    TEST TEST
                    Abaxasdas Test", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

You can compare the columns in a `NA`-safe way using `identical`:

```
mapply(identical, df$A, df$B)
```

To get the output with "YES" and "NO" instead of `TRUE` and `FALSE`:

```
ifelse(mapply(identical, df$A, df$B), "YES", "NO")
```

#### Output

```
> df$Output <- ifelse(mapply(identical, df$A, df$B), "YES", "NO")
> df
          A    B Output
1      <NA> TEST     NO
2      TEST TEST    YES
3 Abaxasdas Test     NO
```

#### An alternative

As joran suggested in a comment, replacing NA's with a value would make the comparison easier. If you don't want  to change the values in the data frame (but maybe you should!), you could use a helper function like this:

```
rna <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), "")
ifelse(rna(df$A)==rna(df$B), "YES", "NO")
```

Comment: @joran - You and @JamesMartherus got me thinking. Not sure if I am being short sighted there, but for the data I am using both column value being `NA` means both are blank and that's `TRUE` for me.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Thanks for pointing this out. I think it is a good habit to avoid using names such as `data` which is a function in package `utils`. But then again, of course, I should not have used `df` which is a function in `stats` (density function of the F distribution). So it's probably difficult to avoid name clashes altogether.

Comment: @joran - Agree. But am I not comparing two same values by replacing `NA` with `non-NA`? Is it coding standard related issue you see?

Comment: the solution with `identical` works with two NA's as well: `identical(NA, NA)` evaluates to `TRUE`. I'm not sure it's good it works this way as technically, I think, you don't know whether two `NA`'s are identical as the actual values are not known. But that's a different issue.

Comment: @joran I sort of agree but then again, this is exactly the kind of technical comparison that was asked in OP. For actual data values, if NA is used in its intended meaning, it is incorrect to say that "TEST" and `NA` are NOT identical. These two values could just as well be identical, it is just that we don't know, so the result of the comparison should be `NA`. So I agree that using `identical` is, in a sense, a hack, but in that very sense, the whole question is hacky-ish, so why not use a hack here :)

Answer (score 6):

You could use `case_when` from dplyr. Adjust the first case output to whatever you want.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(output = case_when(is.na(A) & is.na(B) ~ NA_character_,
                            is.na(A) | is.na(B) ~ 'NO', 
                            A == B ~ 'YES',
                            TRUE ~ 'NO'))
#           A    B output
# 1      <NA> TEST     NO
# 2      TEST TEST    YES
# 3 Abaxasdas Test     NO
```

Answer (score 2):

@lebatsnok has a good answer.
If we do not need `ifelse`, I would do:

```
data <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "A B
                        NA  TEST
                       TEST TEST
                       Abaxasdas Test")

    data$output <- NA
    data$output[as.character(data$A) == as.character(data$B)] <- "YES"
    data$output[as.character(data$A) != as.character(data$B)] <- "NO"
    data$output[is.na(as.character(data$A)) | is.na(as.character(data$B))] <- "NO"

> data
          A    B output
1      <NA> TEST     NO
2      TEST TEST    YES
3 Abaxasdas Test     NO
```