# Comparing data.table columns with NAs in numerical columns

Tags: r, data.table

I just came across an odd observation today that `NA`s in a column inside a data.table don't return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but just `NA`. This question [Comparing Column Values With NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598576/comparing-column-values-with-na) has an answer, but it only refers to character type columns, where changing `NA` to `''` won't affect the data.
Is there a way to compare the data and get back a `TRUE` or `FALSE` without changing the data type of the column?

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(a = c(1:10)
       , b = c(1:4,NA,6:10))

dt[a != b,]
```

In this case I would expect to get the 5th row, because 5 is not equal to NA in my opinion. If anyone could provide some background on why that happens, would also be great.

Comment: Like you just said comparing to NA return NA instead of TRUE or FALSE that's why it doesn't give the "expected" result of 5 being different than NA and changing NA by '' does work with number too.

Comment: No, it does not work with numbers and results in NA again if the column is integer.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and replace the NA by '' and it worked

Comment: Well, but then the column is character from the beginning and not integer.  If you want to change it via `dt[is.na(b), b := '']` it won't work.

Comment: See [Comparing Column Values With NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57598576/comparing-column-values-with-na/57598800#57598800)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to data.table, it's just how `==` and `!=` work in R. But, you can solve by defining a function using `data.table::fcase` and using that instead of `==`.

The justification for the base behavior is that if a value is missing, it could be equal to `5` or not, we don't know. So, the result of the comparison is also missing when one value is missing.

```r
library(data.table)

same <- function(x, y){
  fcase(is.na(x) != is.na(y), FALSE, 
        is.na(x), TRUE,
        rep(TRUE, length(x)), x == y)
}

x <- c(1, NA, NA, 4)
y <- c(1, 2, NA, 5)

same(x, y)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
x == y
#> [1]  TRUE    NA    NA FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok, thanks. Then I need to add my expert knowledge to tell R that the values are not the same ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also try `%in%` instead

```
dt[! (a %in% b)]
```